# How to raise an event from vb6 module?

Tags: vb6

I have developed a custom visual basic 6 control and declared a few custom events. Is it possible in vb6 to raise these events from a module or I need to implement a special "proxy" methods in my control to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**RaiseEvent:**

> Compile error:
>   Only valid in object module.

(Which makes sense.)

Yes, you need a `Friend` method on your class that you would call to raise events from your module:

#### Class:

```
Public Event Click()

Friend Sub OnClick()
  RaiseEvent Click
End Sub
```

#### Module:

```
someVar.OnClick
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not entirely the answer you are looking for, but it is possible to use Event-like procedures from plain Modules:

First define a Callback Interface:
IEventsClient (Class Module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PropertyChanged(sender As Object, property As String)
End Sub
```

MyModule:

```
Option Explicit

Public EventClients As Collection

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(property As String)
    Dim eventsClient As IEventsClient
    Dim element As Variant

    For Each element In EventClients
        Set eventsClient = element
        eventsClient.PropertyChanged MyControl, property
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub RaiseSomePropertyChanged()
    OnPropertyChanged "SomeProperty"
End Sub
```

The main Form:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IEventsClient

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Entry point of the application'
    Set MyModule.EventClients = New Collection
    MyModule.EventClients.Add Me
End Sub

Private Sub IEventsClient_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, property As String)
    If TypeOf sender Is MyControl Then
        Select Case property
            Case "SomeProperty"
            '   DoSomething'
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a useful technique, but you're right, I don't think it's what the OP was asking for